# Sybase SQL: "[...] where [...] '?' in (COLUMN_2 , COLUMN_3 , COLUMN_4)"

Tags: sql, sybase

In a Sybase sql file I have the following statement:

```
if exists (select 1 from TABLE_NAME where COLUMN_1 = @variable_name and '?' in (COLUMN_2 , COLUMN_3  , COLUMN_4)
```

What does the following part of the statement do? :

```
and '?' in (COLUMN_2 , COLUMN_3  , COLUMN_4)
```

Comment: Are you sure it is `and '?' in` and not `and ? in`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tests if the operand on the left is in the list on the right.  The list can contain column references and expressions

So this tests if any of the three column values are `'?'`.

It is equivalent to:

```
where (column1 = '?' or column2 = '?' or column3 = '?')
```